# Extracting headings from post in Wordpress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

On my home page of my WordPress blog I want to extract headings wrapped in `<h3>` tags in my post and only display those under the title.

I've been setting `the_content();` to a variable and trying to use preg_match_all to extract tags and text but it doesn't seem to work. It just displays the title and no content underneath.

Is this the best way to do this or is there an easier way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) `get_the_content();` to return value as string and not as echo.